# StackPrinter: The Stack Exchange Printer Suite

Tags: app, api-v2, website, python, google-app-engine

### UPDATE:

**Version 1.1 - MySE section, PrettyPrint, StackPrinter API**

### Screenshots:

#### App Homepage

[image: Homepage screenshot]

#### Printable view

[image: Printable view screenshot]

### Logo:

[image: Logo]
http://www.stackprinter.com

**StackPrinter** is a website that pulls the main details of a given question, all its answers, comments and votes  formatting them in a simple essential printable view.

I've created this micro web application basically to add a *"Printer-Friendly"* feature to the Stack Exchange Network sites, trying to remove some `@Media Print CSS` limitations like hidden comments, pagination and empty spaces. (rationale [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36709/printer-friendly-button/36743#36743))

Other features:

- *Addons:*

  1. [Greasemonkey script](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/77298.html) - Adds a Printer-Friendly button on question's page (FF|Chrome)
  2. [Bookmarklet](http://www.stackprinter.com/) - Allows you to print a question directly from question's page
- *Favorites:*  lets you browse and print favorites users's questions from:

  1. The Stack Exchange Network
  2. Delicious social bookmarking
- *TopVoted:* top voted questions by tags
- *TopPrinted:* StackPrinter top printed questions
- *Deleted:* popular [deleted questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/73455/popular-deleted-questions-list) archive
- *MySE:* for printing all your Stack Exchange stuff

#### Demo

*Printable question:*
[What should a developer know before building a public web site? - Stack Overflow](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?format=HTML&question=72394&service=stackoverflow)
[Recovering a lost website with no backup? - Super User](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?format=HTML&question=82036&service=superuser) 
[Good tools that fit on a thumb drive - Server Fault](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?format=HTML&question=261&service=serverfault)
[Jon Skeet Facts? - Meta Stack Overflow](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?format=HTML&question=9134&service=meta.stackoverflow)
[API Documentation and Help - Stack Apps](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?format=HTML&question=1&service=stackapps)

*Favorites:*
[Jon Skeet - Stack Overflow](http://www.stackprinter.com/favorites?username=jon+skeet&service=stackoverflow)
[Jeff Atwood - Stack Overflow](http://www.stackprinter.com/favorites?username=jeff+atwood&service=meta.stackoverflow)
[Zoredache - Server Fault](http://www.stackprinter.com/favorites?username=Zoredache&service=serverfault)
[wil - Super User](http://www.stackprinter.com/favorites?username=wil|4386&service=superuser)
[gangsta75 - Delicious](http://www.stackprinter.com/favorites?username=gangsta75&service=delicious)

*TopVoted:*
[python tag - Stack Overflow](http://www.stackprinter.com/topvoted?service=stackoverflow&tagged=python&page=1&pagesize=30)
[discussion tag - Meta Stack Overflow](http://www.stackprinter.com/topvoted?service=meta.stackoverflow&tagged=discussion&page=1&pagesize=30)

*Deleted:*
[What's your favorite "programmer" cartoon?](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?format=HTML&service=stackoverflow&printer=false&question=84556)

### Code

Language: Python
Platform: [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/)
Framework: [webpy](http://webpy.org/)
Source: [github](http://github.com/systempuntoout/stackprinter)
Api: [/export](http://www.stackprinter.com/docs/api.txt)
License: [BSD](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/BSD/)

### Info

- [ChangeLog](http://www.stackprinter.com/docs/changelog.txt)
- [Todo](http://www.stackprinter.com/docs/todo.txt)
- [Submit issues](http://github.com/systempuntoout/stackprinter/issues)
- Current version: **0.9.9.3**

### Contact

[image: Contact info]

### Credits

- The Team
- [Jonathon Watney](https://stackapps.com/users/36/jonathon-watney) (sopy library)
- [Michael Noll](http://www.michael-noll.com/wiki/Del.icio.us_Python_API) (python delicious)
- [Balpha](https://stackapps.com/users/43/balpha) (unicorn provider)
- [George Edison](https://stackapps.com/users/18/george-edison) (SE logos)
- [Jon Seigel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/36709/printer-friendly-button/36743#36743) (idea)

Comment: Good job. The questions are formatted nicely! :)

Comment: that is brilliant!!!  If only this could be a real part of SO!

Comment: oh man!  also, why don't you modify it so it displays the actual value of the link.  Displaying just the text doesn't mean a lot unless you can view the URL as well

Comment: the url.  Just blue text tells me nothing.  I want to see the actual URL so I can type it in later :)

Comment: How about doing what Wikipedia does, and have all the links at the bottom of the page? Then just use `[1]`, `[2]`, etc. in the posts.

Comment: @George do you think it would be useful?

Comment: What if I am going to make more than 10K prints per hour?

Comment: @Koning Amazon Forest will disappear in no time.

Comment: @sys: I think so - if there were a lot of links, the pages would be much easier to read.

Comment: No I mean the API request limit

Comment: @Koning You will get the unicorn error page (the same you get trying to search an unrecognized id Example:666). Why are you asking per hour?10K limit is per day

Comment: How about offering to shorten urls automatically? It could make it easier or faster to visit links off the printout.

Comment: I think this is really simple and clever, not sure about the name though.

Comment: @Toby thanks :).Do you have any suggestion for the name?

Comment: PrintOverflow, StackOverflowPrinter, PrintYourQuestion - no great ones, just StackPrint just doesnt work for me.  Great idea though.

Comment: @Toby, StackPrint is automatically beter than anything with "overflow" in the title as overflow is specific to one site only, and it's the Stack API (stackapps.com?)

Comment: @Toby i thought you were arguing on the second part of the title "The Stack Overflow Trilogy Printer Suite", i don't like it too much :). Actually i like StackPrinter.

Comment: @badp it would mean a full blown shorten urls service on stackprinter; anyway if you want to add it, source code is on github :).

Comment: @systempuntoout, [interfacing with services like is.gd is no rocket science](http://gist.github.com/451227) and I'm kinda swamped with university but I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @badp Sorry but your solution in not feasible because Gae imposes a 30 seconds limits per request. In this 30 seconds, StackPrinter via UrlFetch pulls all the questions details from Stack Exchange (you have questions with hundreds of answers!); adding more data fetching from the service you suggest would surely exceed the 30 seconds limit (there are questions with hundreds of url to shorten). Like i said, it would mean a full blown shorten urls service on stackprinter. (in bocca al lupo per gli esami)

Comment: @sys: You and me are the fast ones when it comes to updating our apps for v0.9 of the API!

Comment: TREE KILLER!!!! 8-p

Comment: @code :-))), actually i use StackPrinter to save in Pdf for my eReader; i don't have a printer @Home.

Comment: Great application -- there are still a few cases where a nice printout beats reading something on the screen.

Suggestion: include the original question URL in prominent fashion near the top of the printout. That would be a good reference from the printed page back to the online version.

Comment: @BrianC thanks Brian, glad you like it :).API does not return the original question url with the slug at the moment.Anyway i could add something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/ that would work.If you think it is worth, i will add it without any problem.

Comment: @BrianC added as requested.

Comment: Please consider listing StackPrinter on [StackList](http://stacklist.quickmediasolutions.com/).

Comment: @George Done!Vote it up..there and here!

Comment: @sys: Thank you! Feel free to suggest new features you would like to see there.

Comment: @Brian: Sorry, what change...?

Comment: be good if you could add a users print page (like with their favourites, but with their name and rep and badges in the top left)

Comment: a big list with all the Stack Overflow users?

Comment: no I mean like the details of one user, so the user ID is entered as a parameter and then it returns a page about that user.

Comment: @jon can't you just print the user's page? What kind of limitation do you see?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The same reason why I don't print a question on the main site, it wastes ink.

Comment: @Jon ok, got it :), I will have a look at it

Comment: I have to say that I don't like the output, harder to read and code isn't formatted with the correct colors. Could there be an optional output for how it is printed?

Comment: @WmasterJ what kind of options you would like to see?

Comment: Well one thing that makes SO really good is the visual cues that make thing easily readable. I would like a printout that keep the voting number in a better layout. And generally a better typographic solution for the print would be great. Then having the option for code in color and possibly to select which comments of all of comments I want. Maybe I only want nr 1, 4 & 7....just some ideas. But good design. typography and sense of grid in the print will definately help. Haven't installed this yet.....will when these things come.

Comment: What do you mean with *a better typographic solution"? The printing is focused more on the question's content than on the votes/reps etc. I could agree with a not default option for syntax highlighting. Installed? Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: How can I print all questions in a tag?

Comment: @justin using the topvoted section but, something is broken at the moment :) http://stackapps.com/questions/2164/authorized-requests-auth-parameter-seems-broken

Comment: @justin ok, now it's working, As I said use the topvoted feature with your desired tag.

Comment: Definitely a needed feature of any website. However, it's still not print friendly enough. The code block has a dark background with a white font face. Huh? Talk about a waste of color or black toner.

Comment: @Mark code block, AFAIK, should be black color on white background. Are you sure?

Comment: where's a userscript link that I can click and install in Chrome? userscripts. userscripts.org page doesn't have it

Comment: yes it has, http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/77298 top right of the page, the install button.

Comment: When using [The Printliminator](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ThePrintliminator/) bookmarklet, one can quickly remove certain parts of a page. To use that effectively: would it be feasible to add a parent `<div>` per answer, and for the comments?

Comment: www.mathoverflow.net is not supported

Comment: @UnadulteratedImagination mathoverflow is now supported!

Comment: Will this break soon with the recent bug fix? [Bring back the <10k trick for viewing a deleted question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/187544)

Comment: @DannyBeckett Nope! StackPrinter is based on SE Api.

Comment: mySE started responding with an error message :`Error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.` Any ideas?

Comment: @sgun hi there, I've tried just now and it seems to work correctly. Can you give it another shot please?

Comment: A bit pity that it shows the ads sometimes.

Comment: @kenorb just add `&printer=true` at the end of the url if you don't want ads.

Comment: How about printing answers through answer id?

Comment: @Pandya When I will be less busy on my work, I might add a new route on StackPrinter API just to handle your request.

Comment: @Pandya Printing answers by id is now supported, check the [Api doc](http://www.stackprinter.com/docs/api.txt) (let me know if you have problem).

Comment: @systempuntoout ok. Where to enter answer id? as I can't find such option at [Homepage](http://www.stackprinter.com/). I've tried by `/export?answer=[id]` but it doesn''t work.

Comment: @Pandya try with [this](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=128703&service=meta.stackexchange&answer=128707) example.

Comment: @systempuntoout Yes, adding `&answer=[id]` is working fine. Thanks!

Comment: to be https compliant, it's time to update the bookmarklet regex to `^https?://(.*?)\.com/questions/([0-9]+)/`

Comment: I have been using Brett Terpstra's "Answered" (http://brettterpstra.com/projects/answered/) bookmarklet. It offers some of the same functionality, but StackPrinter offers more options for archival purposes.

Comment: Is there no way to 'print all' questions or answer by a particular user?

Comment: Is Meta Stack Exchange supported on MySE? I couldn't find the option in the dropdown.

Comment: @astonearachnid ..at the top of the dropdown.

Comment: Not working :(((

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Addons

[Stackprinter](http://www.stackprinter.com) allows you to print directly from Stack Exchange sites using **Greasemonkey script** or an handy **bookmarklet**.
[Greasemonkey script](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/77298) adds a Printer-Friendly button to the question you are browsing (Firefox and Chrome both supported).
[Bookmarklet](http://www.stackprinter.com) is useful if Greasemonkey is not an option and has the same effect of Printer-Friendly button, allowing the print of the question straight from the question page.

[image]

### Favorites

[Favorites](http://www.stackprinter.com/favorites) allows you to browse and print your favorite questions or other users favorites.
Stackprinter supports all Stack Exchange sites plus Delicious social bookmarking service.
Just star or save your questions and browse Stackprinter to print all of them later.

*Users search*
[image]

*Favorites result*
[image]

*[Q]uicklook*
[image]

*Delicious result*
[image: link text]

### TopVoted

[TopVoted](http://www.stackprinter.com/topvoted) allows you to browse and print the best questions searched by tags.

*Tags search*
[image: link text]

*TopVoted result*
[image: link text]

Comment: Is there no way to 'print all' questions or answer by a particular user?

Answer (score 5):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)I asked this as a question, but apparently the convention is to report bugs/feature requests in the announcement thread. 
It appears, that the [MathJax extension mhchem](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#mhchem) is currently not enabled in the StackPrinter app. This is rather inconvenient for most of the chemistry.se questions and answers. It would therefore be nice if this feature could be enabled for the StackPrinter app.

Example:
Please consider the [sandbox on meta.chemistry.se](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/388/4945) and its [printed version](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?format=HTML&service=meta.chemistry.stackexchange&printer=false&question=111) (also see the screenshot below). You can see in the first equation of my post the red `\ce`. I enabled the mhchem package manually via `\require{mhchem]` after that and the same command renders now.

[image: printed result]

Comment: I will take a look at it, is this extension available on Cdn?

Comment: I do not know what Cdn is. The extension is part of the whole MathJax package. It is probably just a variable that has to be toggled, since it is already available, as the screenshot proves. Thanks for having a look.

Comment: Oh OK, it should be easy to fix.(maybe tonight)

Comment: Should be fixed, give it a try.

Comment: @systempuntoout It works like a charm, thank you very much. Great app!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a small script ([stackprinter](https://github.com/kenorb/binfiles/blob/master/stackprinter)) which uses Stack Printer from the command-line:

```
#!/bin/sh
type wkhtmltopdf || { echo >&2 "wkhtmltopdf command is required. Aborting."; exit 1; }
: ${1?"Usage: $0 (url)"}
URL=$1 && shift
HOST=$(echo "$URL" | grep -Eo "([.[:alnum:]]*?)\.(com|net|org)" | head -c-5)
QID=$(echo "$URL" | grep -o "[0-9].*/" | head -c-2)
PRINTURL="http://www.stackprinter.com/export?format=HTML&printer=true&service=$HOST&question=$QID"
FILENAME=$(curl -s "$URL" | grep -o "<title>[^<]*" | tail -c+8)
wkhtmltopdf $* "$PRINTURL" "$FILENAME.pdf" && echo "'$FILENAME.pdf' saved."
```

Usage:

```
./stackprinter (url)
```

Example (tested on OS X):

```
$ ./stackprinter http://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite
'app - StackPrinter: The Stack Exchange Printer Suite - Stack Apps.pdf' saved.
```

Comment: `head -c-2` doesn't work on macOS, is the intent to get the first string of alphanumerics out of the URL? I guess `sed 's/[^0-9]*//;s/[^0-9].*//'` would do that in a single process.  Of course, using parameter expansion would do it without any external process at all (but require several steps and maybe a temporary variable).

Answer (score 4):

The default bookmarklet javascript has problems when used with mathoverflow. Because annoyingly mathoverflow ends with a `.net`
instead of a `.com`. I made some changes so that it could also work with mathoverflow (feel free to improve on it):

```js
javascript:(
function(){
  var re = new RegExp('^https://(.*?)\.com/questions/([0-9]+)/');
  var group = re.exec(window.location.href);
  if (group==null)
  {
    re = new RegExp('^https://(.*?)\.net/questions/([0-9]+)/');
    group = re.exec(window.location.href);
  }
  if (group!=null)
  {
    var service = group[1];
    var questionid=group[2];
    window.open('http://www.stackprinter.com/export?format=HTML&service='+service+'&question='+questionid);
  }
  else
    alert('Attention: question id not found!');
}
)()
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! Perhaps you could replace `\.com` with `\.(com|net)`?

Comment: I know what you mean. I did not know how to make this work with RegExp but I don't think your suggestion works. I think it's a bit more complicated than that. Anyway, I tried it and it didn't work for me.