# Prevent that posts tagged with app or library enter Community Wiki mode when the owner edits it 8 times

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, meta

I've edited my App **8** times and my question has switched automatically to Community Wiki (I'm aware that it's reported in the faq).
The main reason of these many edits is my shaky english, but I can imagine that a question tagged **app** or **library** could be edited for other valid reasons, as for example to keep the application's documentation updated.

Is it possible to prevent that posts tagged with app or library enter Community Wiki mode when owner edits it **8** times?

Comment: The current behavior is very much `bydesign`, so I suggest retagging this `feature-request` and changing "Is it correct that" to "Prevent".

Comment: Yep, that's my shaky english :).

Comment: + credit where credit due.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a result of direct contact by yours truly with the SO team, the thresholds for CW were relaxed for app/library posts on StackApps *a few weeks ago*.

I will defer to the powers that be to post the specific numbers if/when they deem appropriate, but I can confirm that they are significantly increased from previous values.

Don't go nuts churning your posts though...

Comment: Care to give a ballpark figure?

Comment: @geo - I have asked permission to share. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: I am afraid, it is by-designed at the moment. Please take a look at this [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) on meta

> The post has been edited eight (**8**)
>   times by the original owner.

It is to prevent, question bumping in The Stack Overflow Trilogy Sites.

but stackapps is very new, need to edit many times on those stuff, so you could probably request to raise the limit, may be 10 or 12 or more.

Or you could post demo page links, code samples as an answer, instead of adding those into question, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, IIRC, this always happens on any SE site. This is because the system thinks "Hmmm, the post is being edited 8 times. That's probably a good indication that this is a discussion question and should be made Community Wiki."

Comment: I know, I know. I never said I liked it :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems fixed to me. Isn't it?
I got a +10 for StackPrinter and the [question](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-overflow-trilogy-printer-suite) is no more in Community Wiki mode.

Comment: yes. i bugged so team a few weeks ago to fix it and they emplaced special config values specifically for stackapps.