# Can we merge the 'library' and 'wrapper' tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

There seems to be some fragmentation amongst the tags assigned to wrappers/libraries. Some have [library](/questions/tagged/library), some have [wrapper](/questions/tagged/wrapper), and some have both.

If I'm not mistaken, they are the same thing. Can we merge them somehow?

Comment: we COULD just edit them :)

Comment: That's what I mean... could someone please edit them. I'd edit mine, but I would run into [this](http://stackapps.com/questions/221/prevent-that-posts-tagged-with-app-or-library-enter-community-wiki-mode-when-owne) problem.

Comment: I am not sure, we should merge it or not. But I *think* retagging does not count towards force CW mode

Comment: Better not to take the chance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree. So it is written, so it is done. Behold, no wrapper posts.