# Will Stack Exchange hot questions be provided by the API?

Tags: discussion

I would like to add an "hot questions" section to [StackPrinter](https://stackapps.com/questions/179/stackprinter-the-stack-exchange-printer-suite) that will list the hottest StackExchange questions provided [here](http://stackexchange.com/).
I'm going to fetch those questions using the site's [RSS](http://stackexchange.com/feeds) adding details with successive API calls.
Are there any chances that Stack Exchange hot questions will be provided by the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are currently no plans for an API into the StackExchange.com site.  Given how different it is from an SE-site it'd be a significant undertaking.

Perhaps in the future.

It might be of interest to point out that a great deal StackExchange.com is powered by the API.

Comment: Any plans on this one? Is this _status-planned_?

Comment: bump... any plans...?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/questions?sort=Hot

I don't see why you would need to pull RSS and API when you can get all information with params. e.g.

http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/questions?answers=true&body=true&comments=true&sort=Hot

Comment: thank you poet, i'm aware of hot sorting against single endpoint; Stack Exchange RSS feed give you something more, an aggregation of the hottest questions of the entire Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @system oops. sorry misunderstood the question

Comment: blame my limited english skills :)

Comment: @sys - no, your question is quite clear. i simply rushed to a conclusion.

Comment: API 1.0 deprecated. Anybody can upgrade to 2.0?